# Element listener-class/servlet-name/servlet-class/load-on-startup is not allowed here in my web.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/org/mstc/cloudesurface/config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `element listener-class/servlet-name/servlet-class/load-on-startup/url-pattern` is not allowed here!
if i change the `<web-app xmlns.....version="3.1">` to `<web-app xmlns ... version="2.5">` is ok!
why?
The spring framwork version is 4.3.1 I used

Comment: Can you elaborate the issue? It should work with any version.

Comment: I don't know why but it worked suddenly.